# How to convert a simple query via Laravel Query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert the following query into Laravel query builder :

```
select id from Grpusr where user_id = $u_id and group_id = $g_id
```

I'm able to only put 1 variable :

```
$grpusrow = DB::table('Grpusr')->where('group_id', $g_id) ->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more simpler way to get only single column is using `value`

Try the below code it will only `return` the `id` `(or any other specific column)`

```
$grpusrow = DB::table('Grpusr')->where('group_id', $g_id)>where('user_id', $u_id)->value('id');
```

you can also use `get()` if you want to get all details of that record

```
$grpusrow = DB::table('Grpusr')
                       ->where('group_id', $g_id)
                      ->where('user_id', $u_id)
                      ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

use two where clauses for it.

```
$grpusrow = DB::table('Grpusr')->where(['user_id' => $u_id, 'group_id' => $g_id]) ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$grpusrow = DB::table('Grpusr')
                       ->where('group_id', $g_id)
                      ->where('user_id', $u_id)
                      ->get();
```

Use `get()` instesd of `first()`

`first()` will return one result (single model instance) whereas `get()` will return collection

Answer (score 1):

```
$grpusrow = DB::table('Grpusr')->select('id')->where('group_id', $g_id)->where('user_id', $u_id)->get();
```

`get()` used to get all records, and `first()` used to get only first record according to condition